# React Native - error running "npm start" and "react-native run-android"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-native

Yesterday my React Native project is working well, but today after I open my React Native project and running "`npm start`" or "`react native-run-android`" without adding any codes or libraries yet it always give me error now. I'm just confused I did nothing but I'm getting error.

This is the error I got by running "`npm start`" or "`react-native run-android`" :

> Loading dependency graph...events.js:167
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, lstat 'D:\React Native Projects\TheProject\node_modules\babel-register'
>
> Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError (D:\React Native Projects\TheProject\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:159:10)
>       at Walker.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at D:\React Native Projects\TheProject\node_modules\walker\lib\walker.js:52:12
>       at D:\React Native Projects\TheProject\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! TheProject@0.0.1 start: `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the TheProject@0.0.1 start script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Restart your system and try again

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya already did that...

Comment: I also tried to "npm start" in my other projects and works well. Just this project that I did nothing and this error occurs

Comment: Try npm install, npm link and then react-native run-android

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing would be to install Watchman in mac:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install watchman
```

If you don't have brew, do this first:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: Great! I also did `brew upgrade`.

Comment: what about windows?

Comment: use mac bro instead of windows